# How to use the latest image with ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, terraform, amazon-ecs

I am currently using ECS to deploy a web application. This Application is pushed on my ECR with the `latest` tag but putting new images doesn't seem to change the code at deployment.

I tried to use the answer found here [How do I deploy updated Docker images to Amazon ECS tasks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34840137/how-do-i-deploy-updated-docker-images-to-amazon-ecs-tasks) using `aws ecs update-service --cluster <cluster name> --service <service name> --force-new-deployment`.

I also put `ECS_IMAGE_PULL_BEHAVIOR=always` in my ecs config and  `deployment_minimum_healthy_percent = 0` and `deployment_maximum_percent = 200` in my deployment settings.

I notice that the image digest is matching the `latest` image, but by logging on the container, the code is not different from the previous version. But by executing `docker pull <my_image:latest>` the changes are there.

Comment: What issue did you have with that AWS CLI command? Did it not update the service with your new latest image?

Comment: The service is updated but the code running is different from what it should be:
executing docker pull on my image and running it locally doesn't run the same code..

Answer (score 1):

You need to update task definition first (create new one) and then deploy it.

[ECS task definition](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definitions.html) 
[CLI for register task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ecs/register-task-definition.html#output)

Comment: Then I would have to update a nes task definition without any change in it ? Since the image url would be the same (`012345678910.dkr.ecr.region-name.amazonaws.com/repository-name:latest`) ?

Comment: I tried updating the task definition without any change, and my code is still not updated

Comment: So may be this will help you: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56081320/how-does-latest-tag-work-in-an-ecs-task-definition-and-container-instances-pul